# How to change the background color code block markdown github

Tags: github, markdown

I am using below syntax

````
```yaml
 stages:
   - build
   - test
   - deploy
```
````

This helps me to get proper text color and getting box but how to change the background color of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add gray area in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828779/add-gray-area-in-markdown)

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR: GitHub overrides any styling you apply to your document when it renders it using its own flavor.**

However, for other places you can do this with HTML and CSS if you wrap it in a `<div> ... </div>` pair:

```markdown
# Code

## Vanilla

``python
print("hello world!")
``

## Flavored V1

<div style="background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);">

``python
print("Yo!")
``

</div>
```

> I had to remove a backtick <kbd>`</kbd> from each code section in my example in order to render it properly here.

The file above renders as below on VSCode:

[image]

You can further change the appearance with CSS, however, I wouldn't recommend it.

> P.S: GitHub has global dark themes available under settings.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work for me. When inspecting the generated Github wiki page, the `<div>` doesn't contain the `stype` property, it's rendered as just `<div>` with the resulting regular background.

Comment: @Leonardo, indeed, as I had mentioned in my answer, GitHub overrides your formatting. However, since the question was a bit vague I suggested a way of doing it on other flavors of MarkDown.

Answer (score 0):

There is no black them for code blocks in README, But you can workaround and add some custom styles to the `<pre>` tag or `<code>` like so:

```css
code[class*="language-"], pre[class*="language-"]
  border-radius: 6px
  text-shadow: 0 1px #14161800 !important
  background: #242424 !important
  span.token.operator
    background: none
  span.token.keyword
    color: #866cba
```

Note: It's a `sass` way style.