# How to indent text in DockerHub description box

Tags: markdown, dockerhub

I want to write a description in Docker Hub.  And Docker Hub allows for Markdown in the description box (like GitHub, and I imagine other sites as well).

I'm trying to indent my text. But the known ways to do that, are to either make bulleted list, or write it like `code`, but doing it that was doesn't look good on Docker hub (because of the default line spacing -- puts a white line in between, and it also tends to scroll off the screen).  And if you use `>` for block text, DockerHub makes the font blue.  The other alternative was to use `&nbsp;`, but I really didn't want to have to put `&nbsp;` over and over and over.

Is there any other way to accomplish indentation in Markdown? Particularly for the Docker Hub?[image: example of what it might look like]

Using the man pages format as an example of why I want to do this:

```
NAME
   command - description of command

OPTIONS
       -C  flag_name
              Description of how to use flag.
```

That's why I want to indent.

If you don't use some kind of formatting, the text will get smooshed together and it will be hard to understand.

Like this:

NAME
   command - description of command
OPTIONS
       -C  flag_name
              Description of how to use flag.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with docker.   In the end, I think you will adjust your expectations.  Markdown is not an HTML replacement.

Comment: You're right. Edited question, removing docker tag. My mistake; I really didn't intend to tag it like that in the first place. However, the question is still valid. I'm not suggesting it's a replacement for HTML, I said I was trying to use it in that particular site.  Thanks for your comment.  I edited the question for clarification.

Comment: Related: [Add gray area in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40828779/866026) and possibly [How to apply Color in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35465557/866026). I agree with @user2105103. You may need to adjust your expectations of Markdown, especially when it is being hosted on a third party site.

Comment: Find someone else who is using indent and copy his markdown. If no one else is indenting, why would you indent, it would just look weird.

Comment: Indentation is a _presentation_ concern. Markdown is purely about _content_. Why do you want this text to be indented? Can you tie your reasoning to something semantic, e.g. you are quoting somebody? In that case mark your text as a quotation using `>`. But this may not _indent_ the text; it will style it however quotations are styled on that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective: I want to indent my text, for clarity to the end user.

Problem: My options are limited, due to the nature of working within this [website](https://hub.docker.com). What's provided me, is a text box that accepts markdown, and limited HTML.

Offering a solution:

```
&nbsp;
```