# why does my markdown not render the code block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

Using this https://jonschlinkert.github.io/remarkable/demo/, I'm trying to render out a code block like this :
`code` -> however in my react app, the grey highlight is missing? Why is that? Everything else from markdown seems to work.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 var Remarkable = require("remarkable");
 var hljs = require("highlight.js");

class ProjectApprovalText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.rawMarkup = this.rawMarkup.bind(this);
    this.renderNormal = this.renderNormal.bind(this);
    this.renderEditTextArea = this.renderEditTextArea.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.text !== this.props.text) {
      this.renderNormal();
    }
  }

  rawMarkup() {
    var md = new Remarkable("full", {
      html: false, // Enable HTML tags in source
      xhtmlOut: false, // Use '/' to close single tags (<br />)
      breaks: false, // Convert '\n' in paragraphs into <br>
      langPrefix: "language-", // CSS language prefix for fenced blocks
      linkify: true, // autoconvert URL-like texts to links
      linkTarget: "", // set target to open link in

      // Enable some language-neutral replacements + quotes beautification
      typographer: false,

      // Double + single quotes replacement pairs, when typographer enabled,
      // and smartquotes on. Set doubles to '«»' for Russian, '„“' for German.
      quotes: "“”‘’"
    });
    var rawMarkup = md.render(this.props.text.toString());
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  }

  renderNormal = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
        <button onClick={this.props.editProjectApprovalTextArea}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderEditTextArea = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea
          id="myTextArea"
          onChange={this.props.getChangeFromTextArea}
          defaultValue={this.props.text}
        />
        <button onClick={this.props.saveProjectApprovalTextArea}>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.editTextState
          ? this.renderEditTextArea()
          : this.renderNormal()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectApprovalText;
```

In essence I'm just trying to get the same behavior as seen here on stack overflow.

Comment: Try retuning just rawMarkup in your render.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD did you mean to try this  {this.rawMarkup()}

I got this in return 
"<h2>Code</h2> <p>Inline <code>code</code></p>"

Comment: No, sorry, I meant the variable rawMarkup which is md.render(), that’s already a react element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add gray area in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828779/add-gray-area-in-markdown)